# Possible memory leaks in CallBacks

Tags: java, android

I have a suspicion that there may be memory leaks. Since `ServerManager` will hold the callback link, and this callback will hold the activation link. Will there be memory leaks in this code?

```
Ativity {
    TextView textView;
    Handler h = new MyHandler();

    interface Update{
        void update(Data data);
    }

    private Update listener = new Update() {
        @Override
        public void update(Data data) {         
                textView.setText(data.getText());               
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(100);
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ServerManager.getInstance().addCallBack(listener);//Will keep a link to the implementation of the interface
    }

     private class MyHandler extends Handler {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case 100:
                    textView.setText("бла бла");
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Will CallBack keep a link to the fragment? How to do it better?

Comment: I assumed OtherForegroundService is a Service type, so there are different legit ways to communicate from Activity to Service, etc. via Intent or ServiceConnection(bound service typed). Also, The static method adding the listener is not not even usable. And you did not specify the Thread for your Handler as well..

Comment: This code is for reference only. I want to know if there will be a memory leak ... I corrected the question. Now there will be no confusion ..

Comment: Will CallBack keep a link to the fragment? --> Yes, because the callback is the reference of your Fragment(or whatever implementation of your interface). If the reference is passed via the static method and the reference will be keeping alive whether it's actually alive or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `ServerManager` is a singleton, there is definitely a context leak : it holds a reference to the `Update` instance which (as an non-static inner class) holds a reference to the activity declaring it.

Examples of solution could be :

- Add an unregister method to the `ServerManager` and call it from the symetrical lifecycle callback (`onDestroy` for `onCreate`, `onStop` for `onStart`, ...)
- Use a [WeakReference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference), which doesn't prevent the referenced object to be collected.